# git how pull remote master branch to localhost Specified dir

Tags: git

I need pull remote master branch to localhost Specified  dir "f:/www/mobile"

after i run "git  pull remote-address " ,
but Remote files in the root directory,it's look like this:

```
F:
  |--www
     |-- .git  #merge remote GIt commit
     |-- project
     |-- new_mobile #remote file 
     |-- mobile #empty
```

i wish it's look like this:

```
  F:
      |--www
         |-- .git    #merge remote GIt commit
         |-- project
         |-- mobile  #remote file
```

What should I do?

Comment: Is it correct that your GIT project is named *www*? Is the target of your question how to checkout/clone the project in another folder than the one named after your project or are you asking to checkout the branch within a subdirectory of your project's folder?